# Get a cell UITableView by restorationIdentifier / without indexpath [swift]

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell, indexpath

how can I go to a cell without an indexpath to change the content

That makes sense:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
```

But, uh, every cell has a restorationIdentifier.
Can I change the contents of a cell using restorationIdentifier?

Comment: The way to do this is to update your model, and then call `tableView.reloadData()`.

Comment: Koen, I need to update one specific cell without reloading the table. I'll use:  
`tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()`

But I don't need to call this cell with "indexpath," but with "restorationIdentifier"

Comment: Cells are reused, so any tag or id you add to identify a cell could potentially be lost.